# Read .txt file attachment in Google App Engine email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parsing, email, attachment

I'm working on a web app that users can text from their phones and receive a response using Google App Engine. Naturally though, ever since iOS 6, iPhones don't properly text email addresses. Instead, they send a blank email with a .txt file attached. How can I extract and read this .txt file from the email?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def receive(self, message):
    plaintext_body = ''
    for plain in message.bodies('text/plain'):
        plaintext_body = plain[1].decode()
```

I'm thinking of doing something where if plaintext_body is still empty, it checks for a file with a .txt extension and reads it into plaintext_body, but I am not very familiar with Python or working with emails pragmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message is instance of InboundEmailMessage from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Receiving_mail_in_Python
it should look something like this:

```
def receive(self, message):
    plaintext_body = ''
    for plain in message.bodies('text/plain'):
        plaintext_body = plain[1].decode()

    if not plaintext_body and hasattr(message, 'attachments'):
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            if attachment[0].endswith('.txt'):
                plaintext_body = attachment[1].decode()
                if plaintext_body:
                    break
```

You can also add .strip() to remove spaces/break lines etc when checking plaintext_body.strip()